# File reading input incorrect

Tags: java, file-io, java.util.scanner

I have this problem of my text file not fully loading into the program, it skips multiple text lines and begins in the middle of the file. How do I fix it so it reads all of the code and not just the middle of text file? 
[text file](http://textuploader.com/d8c3)
 - Note the file name is called "hurcdata1" for me.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;

public class Hurricanes2 {

    public static void main(String[] args)throws IOException {

      int [] year = new int [59];
      String [] month = new String[59];
      int [] pressure = new int [59];
      int [] speed= new int [59];
      String [] name= new String[59];
      int [] x = new int [59];
      double [] mp4= new double [59];

    File fileName = new File("hurcdata1.txt");
    Scanner inFile1 = new Scanner(fileName);

    //INPUT  - read data in from the file
    int index = 0;
    while (inFile1.hasNext()) {

       year[index] = inFile1.nextInt();
       month[index] = inFile1.next();
       pressure[index] = inFile1.nextInt();
       speed[index] = inFile1.nextInt();
       name[index] = inFile1.next();
       index++;
    }
       inFile1.close();

       for( int z: year) {
            System.out.printf("%5d %n",z);
       }
    }
}
```

Comment: What format is the text file in?

Comment: the text file is .txt

Comment: I mean the data inside the text file.

Comment: @FlyingKalamari It wouldn't hurt to show a small snippet of the file in the question.

Comment: I tried your code against your file, and I got 59 lines of output. I don't think there is anything wrong in your code. Are you sure you are loading the right file ?

Comment: @M21B8 its the link ....

Comment: @DennisMeng there is a link in the question..

Comment: I just noticed that, my bad! I've just run your code against the file, and i get 59 rows output, in the same order as the text file. what problem do you have with it??

Comment: It might be the program I am using. I am using BlueJ because of school purposes. I think it just has a cap of outputs?

Comment: @benjamin.d It was because of formatting issues that wasn't  listed in the given code.

Comment: @FlyingKalamari I know. It still doesn't hurt.

Comment: @M21B8 It was because of formatting issues that wasn't  listed in the given code.